# How to textbox checks itself

Tags: excel, vba, class

I am trying to do textboxes which would be validating input (for numbers only).

I am still new to classes and am little bit confused about some things, but trying my best to learn.
I have multiple textboxes in userform and want to every one of them to be numeric input only.
For the begining I started to check just one textbox (vzdalenost1).

First code just to create connection between textbox and class

```
Dim chk As New Class1
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set chk.ChkEvents = Controls("Vzdalenost1")
End Sub
```

Second code is actual class module

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents ChkEvents As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub ChkEvents_change()
    If IsNumeric(Me.Value) Or Me.Value = "" Then
        Else
            MsgBox "blablabla"
            Me.Value = ""
        End If
End Sub
```

When I try to write something into textbox "vzdalenost1" excel shows error message "Method or data member not found"..

I have even something like replacing "me.value" for "me.control.value" which didnt work either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword `Me` in this context refers to the class object itself, not the textbox.  Use `ChkEvents` to refer to the textbox - `ChkEvents.Value`.

Here's how you could re-write your code to deal with multiple textboxes.  First, let's give your class a meaningful name, let's call it clsTextbox.  Then, in keeping with the principle of encapsulation, let's declare the object in your class as Private, instead of Public.  This will prevent the public from having direct access to it.  Instead, we'll use a member function to assign a textbox to a class object.  So the code for our class module would look like something this...

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents tb As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub tb_Change()
    MsgBox tb.Name
End Sub

Public Function SetTextbox(ByRef obj As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set tb = obj
End Function
```

Then, for our userform, first we declare a collection at the module level to hold our class objects.  Then, since we will be creating multiple class objects, we declare a class object without the keyword `New`.  Instead, we'll use that keyword each time we create a new object, and then we'll add that new object to our collection.  So the code for our userform would look something like this...

```
Option Explicit

Dim textboxCollection As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Set textboxCollection = New Collection

    Dim cTextbox As clsTextbox
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            Set cTextbox = New clsTextbox
            cTextbox.SetTextbox ctrl
            textboxCollection.Add cTextbox
        End If
    Next ctrl

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.. I got it working except one thing.. 
In userform_initialize I dont want to check for "typename", I want to check for Name of the textbox. When I write code 
If name like "Vzdalenost*" then

It doesnt work. When I use typename it works for all textboxes in userform so I want to not use it.

Comment: It should be `If tb.Name Like "Vzdalenost*" Then`.  Note that the comparison is case-sensitive.  For a case-insensitive comparison use `If LCase(tb.Name) Like "vzdalenost*" Then`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly you want a textbox to accept only numbers, correct?
In that case try this:

```
Private Sub TextboxName_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    char = Chr(KeyAscii)
    KeyAscii = Asc(UCase(char))

Debug.Print KeyAscii
If KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57 Then
    Debug.Print "number"
Else
    Debug.Print "other"
    KeyAscii = 0
End If

End Sub
```

Just replace TextboxName in the Sub name with whatever name you have and it should work.